# Hyperlinks in excel online not working

Tags: excel, hyperlink, onedrive

I am using these hyperlinks in an excel file in onedrive:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\cliff\OneDrive\CoT FMV\CoT FMV Documents\"&N2&".pdf";"View")
```

These hyperlinks work with no errors in the desktop version of MS Excel. I need to share this workbook and multiple users need access at the same time so Excel Online is the answer. However; when I open the workbook in Excel Online, the receive this error:

> Sorry, we couldn't open this link. The link address may be invalid, or you may not have permission to open it.

I realise that `C:\Users\cliff\OneDrive\CoT FMV\CoT FMV Documents\` refers to a local directory, but this is an online directory in my onedrive as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Highlight Column or cells containing Hyperlinks
2. On the ribbon select (insert)
3. In the insert hyperlink box that pops up in "DisplayText" type in
   (Https)
4. Select the "URL:"radio button option and type in (Https) Step 5.
   Click Ok. Now all ofyour hypelinks should be activated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had hyperlinks to jpg's that worked fine locally on the laptop. The links did not work when the file was uploaded to onedrive, even though the files resided in the same place, structure on the onedrive. The workaround I used was to create a second column with a second hyperlink. The hyperlink url was created by going to the jpeg on the the onedrive, clicking on it causing it to open in an additional browser window. That URL was then copied and pasted into the second hyperlink url. If you were always going to have internet access you could use the onedrive url exclusively. I chose the two hyperlink approach so that I would have access to the pictures locally on my laptop when I wasn't online. Also. The onedrive links will open in a browser. The local hyperlinks will open using whatever program they are associated with on the local machine. I have two columns for the hyperlinks. One labeled Local Pics. One labeled Onedrive Pics. Both links work locally. Both links appear in the sheet on onedrive. The only link that works on onedrive is the one created using that URL.